# overload function & procedure , any rules?

Tags: delphi

would like to use the same name for a procedure and a function , can I do this, any regulations on this issue ?

```
 /// first version 
 function RunMyImageProcess (aRect : TRect; aBitmap : TBitmap ):  TPoint; overload ;

 ///  a overload version, this works  , it is simple :-) 
 function RunMyImageProcess (aRect : TRect; aBitmap : TBitmap ; aprocessflag : Boolean):  TPoint; overload ; 

 ///  need now a procedure
 ///  will return 2 Points now !!!
 ///   can I do this in DELPHI ???? 
 procedure RunMyImageProcess (var LowerLeft, Upperright: TPoint; aBitmap : TBitmap ; aprocessflag : Boolean):  boolean; overload ;
```

Comment: When you try it, do you get a compiler error? (After, of course, you fix the syntax errors of not providing a type for each of the `aBitmap` parameters and removing the `boolean` return type for the procedure that doesn't return a value.)

Comment: sorry, fixed syntax error; I can compile my real example, but I#m afraid of side effect while changing   more code  and use identical names for a function and procedure with overload statement

Comment: Code does not compile. Procedures do not have return values.

Comment: If the compiler can't figure out which one to use, you'll get a compiler error and the code won't compile.

Comment: As a answer to your question: "would like to use the same name for a procedure and a function?" Yes, you can.
Just design what manner of usage you like. There are two ways to use them: overloaded functions and default parameters. May be it will be more appropriate for your task: `function foo(const A: string = ''): Boolean;`

Comment: @Franz, Try to simplify your question to just one overload of a function and one procedure with the same name. [this comment will disappear in few minutes]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can have overloaded functions and procedures with the same name.

However, you cannot rely on function return type for overload discrimination. So if you have a function and a procedure with the same argument list, they cannot be overloaded.

I would caution you not to go mad with overloading. There are all sorts of traps that you can fall into. For example, if you distinguish based on floating point or integer arguments it can be hard to be sure which overload you are calling. There is also much scope for confusion when you distinguish between pointers and dynamic arrays, as Embarcadero discovered with the XE3 TStream overloads.

In fact the documentation of the overloading rules is incomplete and the only way to fully understand the compiler's behaviour is by reverse engineering.

Comment: In which case, there would be a compiler error that would tell you so.

Comment: @Ken Yes indeed there would

Comment: @David, so, if I'll call a function without assigning its `Result` to somewhere, could it be treated as a procedure ?

Comment: @TLama That is correct. But only in extended syntax mode: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Extended_syntax_(Delphi)